# Print html with javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, popup

I printing html with popup:

```
var w = window.open('', 'PrintSummary','height=600,width=980,scrollbars=yes');
w.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='lv' dir='ltr'><head>\
<link media='all' href='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/d/css/screen.css' rel='stylesheet' /></head>\
<body onload='window.print();'>some htmll</body>\
</html>");
```

onload event not fired, because FireFox (10.0) continues loading screen.css, but visual css is loaded. Why this is happening?

Comment: Add a `type` attribute to your `<link />` tag. More specifically, since you're loading a CSS file, set the value of the `type` attribute to `text/css`. This probably won't fix your error though, do it anyways though.

Comment: did you try to load remote html using `w.location = url` instead of `w.document.write(...)`?